Remove parenthesis around number with uncertainty in \qtylist ()
This follows from the last comment of this thread.
I would like the output of  \qtylist{370(25); 360(19); 386(14)}{\m}
to be 370 \pm 25, 360 \pm 19 and 386 \pm 14 m, whereas now I'm getting (370 \pm 25), (360 \pm 19) and (386 \pm 14) m.
See following MWE :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    load-configurations=abbreviations,
    separate-uncertainty=true,
    multi-part-units=single,
    list-units=single,
    product-units=single,
    range-units=single,
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

I would like the following list :
\qtylist{370(25); 360(19); 386(14)}{\m}
to render as :
\num{370(25)}, \num{360(19)} and \qty{386(14)}{\m}.

\end{document}

As suggested in the thread, I used the separate-uncertainty=true, multi-part-units=single options, but they do not seem to work for lists.
Is there a workaround ?  (apart from typing the list as individual \qty{}{})

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

is your tex distribution up to date? I get  https://i.sstatic.net/82XqpoRT.png from your code (siunitx 2024-06-14 v3.3.18)

(With a current siunitx version, the log file will tell that option "load-configurations" has been removed in this release.)

Indeed ! I am still using the TeX Live 2023, and my siunitx package version is 2023-11-14 v3.3.9. So I may just need to upgrade. Thanks a lot!

You're welcome!
